# I can't join 3 tables with some condition

Tags: sql, join, count

I have 3 tables:

1. Provinces
2. Cities
3. Residences

Here are the columns of these tables :

`Provinces`:

```
id , name , status
```

`Cities`:

```
id , province_id , name , status
```

`Residences`:

```
id , province_id , city_id , name , status
```

I want all provinces, with number of cities that province has, when cities have at least 1 residence.

For example: province #1 has 10 cities, and each city has 10 residences.

But only 5 cities have `city.status = 1` and have residences, and only 3 cities have residences with `status = 1`.

So the data being returned should be :

```
Province 1 - 3 cities (count cities.id)
```

All 3 cities in province 1 have at least 1 residence with status = 1

How can I query this?

I can't use SQL 3

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks

Comment: Please also show us some sample data in your tables, and the expected result from that sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS city_count
FROM
  residences   AS r
INNER JOIN
  cities       AS c
    ON c.id = r.city_id
INNER JOIN
  provinces    AS p
    ON p.id = r.province_id
WHERE
      r.status = 1
  AND c.status = 1
  AND p.status = 1
GROUP BY
  p.name
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  COUNT(*) AS city_count
FROM
  cities       AS c
INNER JOIN
  provinces    AS p
    ON p.id = c.province_id
WHERE
      c.status = 1
  AND p.status = 1
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM residences
     WHERE status      = 1
       AND city_id     = c.id
       AND province_id = p.id
  )
GROUP BY
  p.name
```